# Maas 1.9 on xenial

Tags: juju, openstack

My aim is to install a stable Mitaka environment with juju. Of course I got stuck. I tried to use trusty as a base but I believe there's only a partial upgrade path available to Mitaka (from icehouse) with many pitfalls.

After having read a lot on the internet, including about conjure-up I believe I can get ahead if I can get an advice regarding the following questions:

Is there a way to install MAAS 1.9(stable) on xenial? I believe this is also required to have a working conjure-up environment with juju 2 ?
If so, please tell me how.

OR

Is there a way to install u full mitaka environment on Trusty without doing an upgrade from icehouse. I have tried the bundles from the charm-store (checked correct nic settings for neutron etc but still got stuck). I prefer to do a manual install with the official repo's as the aim is to build a production ready environment.

What would be the best way to go ahead?

Any tips, references to docs are welcome. Please be as detailed as possible.

Regards,

R

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from [UbuntuForums.org Openstack single node install - Xenial?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321536) verbatim:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cloud-installer/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openstack
sudo openstack-install
```

I've not yet tested this myself, but expect to in a day or so. Yes, it is a single node install. For a more authoritative build with heavier hardware requirements see [openstack-base-xenial-mitaka](https://jujucharms.com/u/openstack-charmers-next/openstack-base-xenial-mitaka/bundle/4).

Based on prior OpenStack releases, I am expecting both these to include some frustrated hair-pulling, but I hold hope that Mitaka has improved deployment.